# How do I echo star character each time decrementing by one

Tags: php, loops

What am trying is this

```
***
**
*
```

And I am doing it like this:

```
<?php
    $val = '*';
    for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++) {
            if($i == 1) {
                echo '***<br>';
            } elseif($i == 2) {
                echo '**<br>';
            } elseif($i == 3) {
                echo '*';
        }
    }
?>
```

Now am sure this is a donkey way to do... I guess I need to use a while loop inside a for loop but not getting how to do it..

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie No, am a well grown man learning PHP, and am learning by accomplishing by taking lil projects like this

Comment: Yes, you need to new the loops. The outer loop will be the `counter`. The inner loop will be responsible for outputting the star `counter` number of times.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie ya I know that but am not getting it correctly, sorry but am learning things so if you guys think it's a homework question than no, it's not, I didn't simply ask you people to give me the code, I wrote, but I know it's not smart

Comment: @AcidicCloud +1 I have been downvoted always when asking question, so now i dont ask them. Keep up spirits and keep asking regardless of downvotes.

Comment: x = x+'*'; echo on the x out of the loop

Comment: I've awarded +1 for everyone for showing me alternate ways too, for accomplishing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ($counter = 1; $counter <= 10; $counter++)
{
    // display star, counter number of times
    for ($star_counter = 1; $star_counter <= $counter; $star_counter++)
    {
        echo "*";
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Atlast what I wanted...now I'll go through this code and learn

Comment: It's been 3 years man, that username needs an update.

Comment: Thanks for this.. Wanted an answer with nested loops ...

Comment: Maybe you should have stated that explicitly. Now most of us assumed you wanted the "least donkey" solution, and a nested loop solution is not what first comes to mind. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

for($i=3;$i>0;$i--)
{
echo str_pad("*", $i,"*");
echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There you go:

```
function stringTree($val = '*', $k = 3) {
    for($i = $k; $i > 0; $i--) {
            echo str_repeat($val, $i).'<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

and then for your specific example you can call:

```
stringTree('*', 3);
```

that will output:

```
***
**
*
```

or go ahead and make it even bigger; for example:

```
stringTree('*', 6);
```

will output:

```
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

or easily change character:

```
stringTree('.', 4);
```

will output:

```
....
...
..
.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_repeat`:

```
str_repeat('*', 4-$i)
```

The whole code:

```
<?php
$val = '*';
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++) {
    echo str_repeat($val, 4-$i) . '<br/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: can you show me how to accomplish this with a loop?

Comment: Beat me to it. :) That's a good solution.

Comment: Thanks but can you show me nested loop example? cuz I want to know the logic behind this so that I can use it in other languages too

Comment: This triggers an error on the `+` of the string. The concatenation operator in PHP is `.`

Comment: @Jeffrey: Of course! That was a typo, I fixed it, thank you very much for the tip

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $val = '***';
    while($val != '')
        echo $val . '<br/>';
        $val = substr($val, 0, -1);
    }
?>
```

This lets you start with as many stars as you want and doesn't require an inner loop.

Comment: `substr($val, 1)` makes more sense than `substr($val, 0, -1);`

Comment: Yeah, not sure why I went for removing characters from the end of the string. I guess both approaches are equivalent in this case, though yours is a bit more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I will explain An understandable way,

```
   $val = '*'; // Your star
    $count= 3; // Number of lines
    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
            $num= $count-$i; //number of lines to come
            for($j=0; $j<$num; $j++) {
            echo "*";
    }
    echo "<br />";
    }
```

Out put

```
***
**
*
```

[Test Here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/)

Answer (score 1):

The obligatory 1-liner, so many ways to do this.

```
for($i=3; $i; print str_repeat("*", $i--) . '<br />');
```

For fun: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4114/print-a-christmas-tree/6783#6783